# have something happening / having something happen / having something happening

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I would like to know the differences between these three sentences.

1. The teacher have the students writing the answers on the whiteboard now.
2. The teacher is having the students writing the answers on the whiteboard now.
3. The teacher is having the students write the answers on the whiteboard now.

Are they all grammatically correct and share the same meaning ?

Comment: You can only say 'both' about two things.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you , I have corrected it.

Comment: (1) should be _has_, not _have_. (2) sounds awkward, (3) is OK, and they all mean the same.

Comment: Perhaps more naturally "The teacher asks the students to write their answers on the whiteboard."

Comment: @KateBunting Thank for your analysis